# iOS 11 Beta - NSURLErrorDomain - code: 18446744073709550617

Tags: ios, afnetworking, ios11

When running my app on iOS 11 beta 5 built with Xcode 9 I see this error from several of our network calls.

> "NSURLError *    domain: @“NSURLErrorDomain” - code:
>   18446744073709550617"

I've never come across this error before and we haven't made any change to the app currently. For networking, we are using **AFNetworking v2.5**

Comment: 18446744073709550617 is an unsigned representation of -999, which is `NSURLErrorCancelled`.

Comment: That happens if the request was explicitly canceled. But I believe it can happen if it was canceled for other reasons, too, e.g. things like invalid SSL certificate or the like, though I cannot attest to that. I'd suggest searching SO for `NSURLErrorCancelled` and check the other possible sources of this particular error.

Comment: Thanks for the response about -999 that is good to know! It turns out it was ssl related. Eventually what I did was add an exception for the api domain and was able to get a reasonable error that said there was an ssl issue. Investigating that showed our cert was weakly signed. We replaced it which resolved the issue.

Comment: The other thing I tried that led me to investigate the ssl cert was that the calls worked when going through the Charles proxy with ssl proxying enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out it was ssl related. Eventually what I did was add an exception for the domain in info.plist and was able to get a reasonable error that said there was an ssl issue. Investigating that showed our cert was weakly signed. We replaced it which resolved the issue.